# How do I delay loading .dlls in a C++-CLI (.net) application?

Tags: .net, dll, import, c++-cli

I'm trying to delay loading my dependent .dlls for a C++/CLI application so that I can test for their existence and warn the user instead of just crashing out.

I've tried adding the dlls to MyProject->Properties->ConfigurationProperties->Linker->Input->Delay Loaded DLLS ...but that just gives me a warning that it's not referencing them:

> 5>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:Util.dll ignored; no imports found from Util.dll

If I delete a .dll and run the application it crashes and wants to send information to microsoft about the missing .dll so it looks like it's still trying to load all the modules at startup and having a fit as a result.

FYI, my app startup looks something like this:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::ObjectModel;
using namespace Microsoft::Win32;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    try
    {
        // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
        Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

        // First make sure we have all the .dlls we need
        ArrayList^ missingDlls = gcnew ArrayList();
        Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly();
        array<System::Reflection::AssemblyName^>^ referencedAssemblies = assembly->GetReferencedAssemblies();
        for each(System::Reflection::AssemblyName^ referencedAssemblyName in referencedAssemblies)
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly^ a = assembly->Load(referencedAssemblyName);
                if( a == nullptr )
                {
                    missingDlls->Add(referencedAssemblyName->Name);
                }
            }
            catch(System::Exception^ e)
            {
                MessageBox::Show("Error loading "+referencedAssemblyName->Name);
            }
        }

        ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The linker's /delayload option only works for DLLs that contain functions compiled to native machine code.  The linker already told you that you don't have any.

The likely scenario here is that your DLL actually contains IL, not machine code.  Which will happen when you compile the source code with /clr in effect and haven't used #pragma managed to turn off IL generation.  IL code needs to be converted to machine code by the jitter.

Your DLL is going to get loaded dynamically, same as /delayload, as soon as the jitter needs type info from the assembly's metadata to generate machine code.  To avoid the dependency on the DLL, you'd have to carefully craft your code so the jitter never needs to load types from your assembly.  Which is a different problem from avoiding *executing* a delay-loaded function.  The exception's InnerException's stack trace should give you a strong hint how that happened.

Comment: What does "IL" stand for? I had a suspicion this was probably going to be more effort than it was worth and from what you've said, it probably is.

Comment: Unfortunately I never get a chance to catch the exception myself and unfurl it so all I've seen is the outer parts in the bug report that Miscrosoft want to send themselves.

Comment: IL == Intermediate Language, what code gets translated to when you compile with /clr.  The jitter translates it to machine code. Subscribe to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to log unhandled exceptions like this.  It can technically be raised before your Main() method starts running if that method uses types from such an assembly.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That's the problem I was alluding to; the exception occurs before I hit the main function.

Comment: Kinda hard to avoid a dependency on an assembly when you use its types in the Main() method.  Move code into a separate method and apply [MethodImpl] to suppress inlining.  Strange that you haven't found any of this helpful btw.  I gotta stop giving 'bad news' answers.

Comment: That got it (moving the method calls into another method). It was useful background information, but I didn't understand the implications you were getting at. That last suggestion nailed the problem though.

Comment: In case anyone else wants it, the [MethodImpl] is called like this: `using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions::NoInlining)]`